# WGET -HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found

Tags: hyperlink, converters, wget

I tried in several ways to make a copy of the website https://www.filmsecession.com/ using the Wget method with these credentials wget>wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no -parent https://www.filmsecession.com/# and others but I can't do it at all, it's for a very important job, the copy only goes to the home page, nothing else appears, anyone who can help me...

étodo do Wget com essas credenciais wget>wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent https://www.filmsecession.com/#